# How did Romans know if their money was debased?

Tags: roman-empire, money

In many moments of Roman imperial history coin was debased, with its silver contents being reduced over time, and in general this was linked with increasing imperial expenditures. In Harper's *The Fate of Rome* (2017) it is stated that Caracalla needed to create a new kind of coin, the *antoninianus*, to be able to pay soldiers after he raised their pay. This new coin was said by the state to be worth two *denarii*, even though its silver contents only reached the mark of 80% of the silver contained in two *denarii*. It seems that this worked for a while.

But in the 250s and 260s the *denarii* and *sesterces* were progressively melted down, eventually disappearing, and the *antoninianus*, the sole remaining silver coin, was debased until it was a billon coin, almost pure vile metal. Harper says that people must have started holding on to good metal, taking coins out of circulation and accelerating the currency crisis. In the author's words, "no other era of Roman history is so productive of coin hoards." (p. 148)

**My question is: How could Romans, in this period and in other periods as well, tell if their coins were being debased?** How could those people that took coins out of circulation know that their silver content was getting lower? Did they keep measuring the density of new coins, or did the state advertise that new coins had less silver? (This would seem counterproductive if the objective of these measures was to pay for the state's debts.)

*(My research so far didn't give any results, as the articles I found were only about debasement as a problem for the Roman Empire, and didn't tell me what I wanted to know)*

Comment: Roman silver coins were [debased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_currency#Debasement) by replacing some of the silver content with copper. If your 'silver' coin starts going green in your pocket, it's probably a good sign that the coinage has been debased!

Comment: Some professional jewellers and other metalworkers would certainly have noticed the debasement. And from there the knowledge would have spread. That said, it's far from certain that most Romans were aware of what's happening. My understanding is that it's not clear that prices actually tracked precious metal content, as you'd expect them to if everyone knew.

Comment: Same way as we know that our money is debased: inflation.

Comment: @sempaiscuba From the Wikipedia article you linked to, it seems that only coins with less than 5% fineness were really different from true silver coins, and I guess lay people could fail to notice big differences in silver content if they didn't get below the 10% mark.

Comment: @Alex This may the case in a Modern setting, but could it be true in a Roman setting? I don't think people kept track of general prices all the time. Also, fluctuations caused by droughts and the likes could mask inflation.

Comment: Why would they know? Why would they want to know?  Merchants and Moneychangers could weigh the coins against standard weights.  It isn't complex

Comment: @James Cook: people don't keep track. When I go shopping and notice that the cheese that I was buying  a month ago is more expensive now, and the same happens with meet and fish, I know that my money is debased.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: I up-voted your comment, then some of my chemistry classes started to come back to me. Alloys don't work that way - which is how and why galvanized steel works. Simply wrapping a little zinc around an iron object is often enough to dramatically slow oxidation. Actually alloying the two metals works even better.

Comment: @Alex: Not necessarily, because for inflation to happen, the populace would have to know that the coinage was debased.  There's a somewhat parallel example within living memory: in the late 1950s/early 1960s, the US debased its former 90% (IIRC) silver coinage (dimes, quarters, half dollars, and dollar coins) with versions containing less silver, and eventually none - the bimetallic versions in use today.  They're readily distinguishable, and many people hoarded the old silver coins, so that they were quickly removed from circulation.

Comment: @jamesqf inflation does not happen because there is more or less bullion in the coins, it happens *because there are more coins*. As money becomes more abundant than goods, its value is reduced (in fact, economics now consider money as just another good). There is no need for people to be aware of the bullion content for inflation to happen. In fact, people hoarding money because they know about the debasing *has the opposite effect*: money is retired from circulation and so keep the value of circulating money high.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens These are [extreme examples](http://www.forumancientcoins.com/numiswiki/images/HoardCoins3.jpg) probably due to the burial environment they were recovered from, but yes, copper alloy coins do turn green - even copper alloyed with silver. The more copper, the higher the tendency to produce verdigris. FWIW, adding zinc to copper to produce a brass alloy doesn't stop the process either.

Comment: @JamesCook Probably. But by the time they got to a standard of 20 parts copper to 1 part silver in "silver" coins of the 270s I suspect that virtually everyone would have noticed what was going on!

Comment: @SJuan76: Yes, inflation can and will happen if there is less bullion in the coins (although that is not the only possible cause).  The worth of a coin (at least in the era we're discussing, pre-fiat currency) is closely tied to the worth of the metal in it.  If an old coin was pure silver, and a new coin was only 10%, it would take 10 new coins to buy what one old one would.  If you increase the number of pure silver coins in circulation (without increasing the actual amount of silver available) their value will not change.

Comment: @jamesqf `If you increase the number of pure silver coins in circulation (without increasing the actual amount of silver available) their value will not change.` That is simply wrong. Increase the relative abundance of a good (money is a good, and the bullion it contains does not matter) and its individual value will go down. Even gold and silver do not have "absolute" value. For example, that was the whole issue behind the [Free silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_silver) movement.

Answer (score 4):

The density of copper (~9 g/cc) is almost 20% less than that of silver (~10.5 g/cc). It wouldn't take a genius of [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes) caliber to repeat the well known ["*Eureka!*" experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(word)#Archimedes) and test coins for precious metal content.

And the moment one person in a community starts discounting certain coins, you can be certain that others would get suspicious as well. It just takes one well educated merchant to start the rumours flying.

Comment: Note, the Archimedes story itself may be a myth, but it was first mentioned by [Vitruvius](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-archimede/) in the first century BC, so regardless density vs. volume was known in Roman times.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with hardness as Silver is soft but becomes much harder the more copper content is present.  Take a known silver coin and a coin in question and setup an experiment where a jewelry hammer hits the coin with the same force.  A pure silver coin should indent with a significantly lower force than the silver/copper coin.  It's a pretty steep curve with a 10% copper impurity being almost twice as hard as a pure silver coin would be.

[image: hardness increase]

image credit here 
http://riograndeblog.com/metal-hardness-how-to-measure-it-and-why-it-matters-for-silver-alloys/

Comment: As this is a history question, is there any evidence Romans did this, or were capable of the necessary precision?

Comment: Never mind a hammer - use your teeth; it is actually more reliable and more easily calibrated without machinery. It ***is well known*** that this technique was used, and commonly.

Comment: @schwern - they were definately capable of it...as pieter points out, your teeth would work to determine pure silver vs 10% copper pretty readily.  Not sure if i can find proof of this practice, though itd be interesting if this is where biting a coin came from